# PHP progress bar can be work with $_SESSION?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

We would like to integrate Jquery Progress bar with PHP. We have implemented $_SESSION, but we are not getting the exact value, according to our requirement.

Please look at our codes .

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Jump for Joy</title> 
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">



 #bardivs {
   width:400px;
  position:relative;
  }
 #progresstext {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
 </style>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#sub").click( function() {
$.ajax({ 
  type : 'POST',
  url : 'http://localhost/tools/ip/html/demo.php',
  dataType : 'html',
  data: {
      camp_url : $('#camp_url').val(),
      captcha :  $('#captcha').val()
  },
  success : function(data){
  $('#message').removeClass().addClass(data).html(data).show(500);
  $("#progressbar").delay(100).hide(200);}


});
  var url = "http://localhost/tools/ip/html/xyz.php";
$(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
    setTimeout(function(){ updateProgress(0); }, 1000);
});

function updateProgress(data) {
    $.get(url+'?progress='+data, function(data) {
        // data contains whatever that page returns     
        if (data < 100) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: parseInt(data)});
            setTimeout(function(){ updateProgress(data); }, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: 100});
        $("#progressbar").delay(100).hide(200);
        }


  }); 
}
   });
 });
 </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="header">
            <h2>Jump for Joy Sale</h2>
        </div>
           <div id="main">
            <div id="bardivs">
    <div id="progressbar"></div> 
    <div id="progresstext"></div>
    </div>
           <div id="message"  style="display: none;">
</div>
 <input type="submit" name="check" id="sub" value="submit">
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

**demo.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$set = $_SESSION['size'] ;
$array = array(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000);
$ab = 1 ;
@$size=sizeof($array);
$size = round(100/$size);
foreach($array as $a){
    echo $a ;
    sleep(1);
$_SESSION['size'] = $set + $size ;  
}
?>
```

**xyz.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(@$_SESSION['size'] <=100) {
    header("Refresh: 1; url=xyz.php");
}
@$_SESSION['size'];
   $set = (int)@$_GET['progress'] + @$_SESSION['size'];
   echo (int)$set ;
?>
```

we are getting the Data after the progress bar process, but not getting the progress bar .

Thanks

PPS

Comment: please put some effort while asking questions, Do I need to read all the code ??.. please specify what are exactly the problem

Comment: we need, a progress bar for our programe built in PHP. above we have applied a jquery function for getting value from PHP. but we are not able to start progress bar first, then rest of the data getting from demo.php,

Answer (score 1):

Is this exactly the code you are using? If so, switch the `sleep(1)` for `sleep(1000)` it could simply be that the demo.php has actually finished by the time your indicator has made a request.

Comment: it can be possible to implement ob_start(), ob_flush() , flush() ?